# Practical use for matching 0 or more times in regex (*)

Tags: python, regex

I am just beginning with regex in python and am wondering if `*` i.e. matching something 0 or more times has utility in practical situations or not. Kindly help.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any specific question about it?

Comment: Sure, there are many practical uses for this. A common use is something where spaces are optional: you want to match 0 or more spaces...

Comment: Definitely agree with the whitespace case.  `*` has been useful many, many times for me.

Comment: @KlausD. not really. I was just curious.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have a substring with fixed start and finish items, which could be separated only with specific separators. For example:
`"cat-cow"`, and you may have many dogs between them, or may not. Like this: `cat-dog-dog-cow` but you don't want to see another animals between them: `cat-horse-cow` is incorrect.
So you may use regexp like `r'cat-(dog-)*cow'`:

```
    import re
    >>> re.match(r'cat-(dog-)*cow', 'cat-cow') is not None
    True
    >>> re.match(r'cat-(dog-)*cow', 'cat-dog-cow') is not None
    True
    >>> re.match(r'cat-(dog-)*cow', 'cat-horse-cow') is not None
    False 
    >>>
    >>> re.search(r'cat-(dog-)*cow', 'cat-dog-dog-dog-cow') is not None
    True
```

Comment: Oh Yeah! Makes sense. Thanks.